# Captcha won't show up when load contact form by Static Block

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, contact-form, captcha

I am getting captcha at contact us page. But when same file is called in static block, contact us form works fine but captcha does not occur.

Kindly suggest any solution.

Comment: Where have you added the captcha block and how?, what is the type of your captcha

Comment: I have used this [extension](https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html)

Comment: And called phtml file in static block as {{block type="core/template" template="mcrecaptcha/contacts/form.phtml"}}

Comment: I haven't the code of this extension, can you share please the layout.xml of this extension ?

Comment: Its working in my rwd theme but in my custom theme its not working

Comment: did you tried my code ?, have youcsome js errorc?

Comment: its already written in file

Comment: It's difficulte to debug without the code, please share it

Comment: Tried this ? https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the js issue,

in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/contacts/form.phtml`

replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

With:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
    function validateCaptcha() {
        var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
          if(v.length == 0) {
               jQuery('#error-g-captcha').show();
               return false;
          }else {
              jQuery('#error-g-captcha').hide();
              return true;
          }
    }
//]]>
</script>
```